# Generate XML, incorrect content-length

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Im using the accepted answer here: [Transmit generated XML file without saving to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883193/transmit-generated-xml-file-without-saving-to-disk)

How do i know the content length? Im using `doc.OuterXml.Length.ToString()` but im missing like 20-30 characters at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Content-Length` header counts bytes, not characters. `String.Length` counts characters. You probably want something along the lines of

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", 
                   Response.ContentEncoding.GetByteCount(output).ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably passing XML over a http request? In such a case, the data is being passed as bytes. You want the length in bytes, not the length in characters. So, get the length of those bytes, not the length of the string.

In this case, it's going to be using an encoding, probably UTF16, but C# calls it unicode.

You have a couple of methods that might help:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(someString);
Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(someString);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the XML is not too big, you can write it to a `MemoryStream`, and then transmit the content of the `MemoryStream`.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        // write your XML here...
    }
    Response.ContentLength = ms.Length;
    Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.Length);
}
```